# Write nodeJS Resful services without middleware framework

Tags: node.js, restful-architecture

I want to write node restful API services with MongoDB with out express or hapi.js any middlware js, where do I start from, I have expertise of using JavaScript and no idea about node or middleware?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a good reason why people use frameworks like happi or express for node, the most important being that they don't want to reinvent the wheel again.

While you can certainly do it, it is strongly discouraged. Your code won't be as tested, as safe nor as clean as the code of a framework with years of existence and millions of users.

Still, if you insist, your first step should be to get familiarized with the extensive documentation of Node.js:

https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v9.x/docs/api/

You will need a mix of a great part of those modules so ... good luck and have fun I guess?

I would suggest the URL module as a start point ...

Comment: Thank you @Flame_Phoenix

Comment: If this helped you, make sure to select it as answered :P